# What is the best authentication mode for asp.net application using SQL Server 2005 Express?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, authentication

I have inherited an asp.net 2.0 application that uses a SQL Server 2005 Express database and I am grappling with the authentication mode.

I have read that windows authentication is more secure and locally that works just fine. I use the default machine account and a trusted connection in the connection string similar to :

```
value="trusted_connection=True;server=MYMachineName\SQLExpress;Database=DatabaseName;Pooling=false"
```

On the server though, I find myself having to grant more privileges to the aspnet user (execute, update) in the database and am wondering if this makes sense after all. The login verification is actually handled by the application.

Does it make more sense to set up a database user and use those credentials in the connection string? Would this be an acceptable connection string?

```
value="Server=myServerName\SQLExpress; Database=myDataBase; User Id=myUsername; Password=myPassword;"
```

Comment: SQL Authentication is easy to setup, easy to understand, and very reliable.  Windows authentication might be a bit more secure, but it's so much harder that it's almost never worth it.

Comment: well .. it's partly working. I enabled windows and sql authentication on the database server. I  created a sql server user account, granted it db_owner privileges for the db in question.  On the server I can log on and do whatever I need to do.  However, there must be something wonky with my connection string because I cannot gain access through the .net app.  I get a general login failed for user "so and so".  :(

Comment: oops.  There was a missing ; in my connectionstring. This seems to work. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re not in a need for a very high security you’ll be doing just fine with sql authentication.

Try this connection string instead

```
<add name="connstring" connectionString="Data 
Source=myServerName\SQLExpress; Initial Catalog=myDataBase; 
Persist SecurityInfo=True;User ID=myUsername; Password=myPassword" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I think sql authentication is the way to go ... for me anyway.